# MS Access, changing language of a form

Tags: ms-access

Trying to create two MS Access forms, where im trying to change the labels and header to be in different languages respectively. I cant find a language option under properties, can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Access does not have intrinsic translation capability. You have type text in whatever language alphabet you want. Apparently, should be able toggle db input language. Then need to know which keys produce which characters. Suggest you Google topic. Building a multi-lingual db seems complicated https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/908560-how-implement-multi-lingual-database

Comment: Might have to be a Windows setting to switch languages https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/switch-between-languages-using-the-language-bar-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258